# How to choose the current user

Tags: angularjs

[image]I want to get just the current user with the ID I tried different ways but I could not find solution, I will provide code of my CRUD so there is a list with all users, my changes are bad so better look at this code, I want to see the info of user Spot only:

```
**controller.js**

.controller('rootCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.pageTitle = "User Settings";
})

.controller('listCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $state, $stateParams, userSettingsService) {
    $rootScope.pageTitle = "List User";
    $scope.mList = {};

 userSettingsService.getAll().then(function (response) {
            $scope.mList = response.data;
        }, function (response) {
        });

 $scope.doEdit = function (eUser) {
        $state.go('edit', { nID: eUser.ID });
    }
```

**Here is the code of App.js**

```
enter code here
 .state('list', {
        url: '/list',
        templateUrl: 'templates/list.html',
        controller: 'listCtrl'
    })

    .state('view', {
        url: '/view/:nID',
        templateUrl: 'templates/add-edit-view.html',
        controller: 'viewCtrl'
    })
```

*HTML PAGE connection*

```
enter code here


<tbody ng-repeat="eUser in mList.ListUser">

                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ eUser.Username }}</td>
                        <td>{{ eUser.Fullname }}</td>
                        <td>{{ eUser.Organization }}</td>
                        <td>{{ eUser.Occupation }}</td>
                        <td>{{ eUser.Gender }}</td>
                        <td>{{ eUser.Email }}</td>
```

Comment: post your edit button template code

Comment: .state('edit', {
        url: '/edit/:nID',
        templateUrl: 'templates/add-edit-view.html',
        controller: 'editCtrl'
        })

Comment: @ template means HTML

Comment: Here you are: <button type="button" style="float:left; width:100%; display:inline;" ng-click="doEdit(eUser)">Edit</button>

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$state.go("edit", {"nID":  eUser.ID });
```

Comment: Maybe you did not understand what I want, I want to appear on the page only the user info of the current user and I am seeing now all other users who are registered. My Edit button works perfect! I just want to have the info of user Spot there.

Comment: you have all the information of the user Spot ,inside the fucntion $scope.doEdit = function (eUser) {

Comment: Yes but how can I get only this values when I press the button Profile Page, because when I press now the button I am seeing these all users but I need only for the user Spot

Comment: just create a new $scope variable $scope.selectedUser , and assign the user inside the edit function, then you can use the same variable in the profile page

Comment: I tried but I am new in Angular.. I followed different explanation here in stachoverflow but I could not do it. I am good in Ruby but not Angular. If you can help me I will be happy.

Comment: I do not know how to call it also in the html code it is ng-repeat, but this is for all users when it is about 1 user what should it be?

Comment: Just add a function into your ng-repeat, with a parameter that would match the current clicked user ? if I get it right

Comment: Devmoutarde that is right but how to do it? Could you please write the code? Here is all the code https://plnkr.co/edit/covcuPcVFGe2sT1XVSqf?p=preview